# How to encrypt a binary file with HTML5 File API and upload to server

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, filereader, cryptojs

I need to encrypt and upload file to Apache/PHP server with [HTML5 FileReader API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) and [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)

I've done the following succesfully

- Read file with FileReader API
- Convert file to base64 with `readAsDataURL()` function
- Encrypt it with the following

  CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(e.target.result, password);

But I couldn't manage to send it to server as a `File` object because I already converted it to text object and I can't convert back it to a file. The following is my javascript file and server-side snippet.

---

app.js

```
 var reader = new FileReader();

 // Read file callback!
 reader.onload = function (e) {

     // Use the CryptoJS library and the AES cypher to encrypt the 
     // contents of the file, held in e.target.result, with the password

     var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(e.target.result, password);


     //SEND FORM DATA
     var data = new FormData($("#fileinfo")[0]);

    /*The following line doesn't work because I'm not adding a File object, 
    * I'm adding file already converted to Base64 format
    */
     data.append('file-0','data:application/octet-stream,' + encrypted);

     $.ajax({
         url: 'upload.php',
         data: data,
         cache: false,
         contentType: false,
         processData: false,
         type: 'POST',
         success: function (data) {
             //alert(data);
         }
     });

 };
```

---

upload.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_FILES); //prints empty array
var_dump($_POST); //prints file as string 
?>
```

Comment: this functionality already implemented by me...while uploading it can you remove `data:application/octet-stream` cause of which you can't able to decrypt it

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer the new Draft on w3
Here is a working code if anyone need

```
var reader = new FileReader();

// Read file callback!
reader.onload = function (e) {

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(e.target.result, password);

var data = new FormData($("#fileinfo")[0]);

var encryptedFile = new File([encrypted], file.name + '.encrypted', {type: "text/plain", lastModified: new Date()});

data.append('file[0]', encryptedFile);

$.ajax({
     url: 'upload.php',
     data: data,
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     type: 'POST',
     success: function (data) {
         //alert(data);
     }
 });

};

reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Comment: have you moved any further with this?

Comment: @niieani, I didn't. This code runs OK at least for Chrome.

Comment: that's wrong... it should be:

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(e.target.result.split(",")[1], password);